# How to fix “/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found”?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chromium, google-chrome-os, glibc

When I tried to compile `chromeos_unittests` of `chromium`, these errors showed:

```
❯ autoninja -C out/Cros/ chromeos_unittests
ninja: Entering directory `out/Cros/'
[0/1] Regenerating ninja files
[10299/10299] LINK ./chromeos_unittests
./out/Cros/chromeos_unittests: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ./out/Cros/chromeos_unittests)
```

(To be more accurate, the link phase threw the error message.)

Platform:

```
❯ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

The output of `ldd --version`:

```
❯ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu11.3) 2.23
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

Comment: Pleas ellaborate a bit more. What are you trying to do, when you get this error? What is the output of `ldd --version`? AND PLEASE DON'T TRY TO AIMLESSLY UPGRADE OR DOWNGRADE GLIBC. You can break you system very very easily.

Comment: Thanks, @Malik! 
The description has updated.

Comment: You say you’re _compiling_ the unit test project, but are you really? The error indicates otherwise. Please try cleaning the build folders.

Comment: @DanielB Yup, to be more accurate, the link phase threw the error message. (Clean the build folders and try again the same error message appearing.)